# Python scripting for a web app

Tags: python, sandbox

I plan to create a web app where users could create their accounts and in simple text IDE create their own Python scripts that would be executed at the server side.

What is the safest way how to handle such execution? I mean, it is so easy to write a simple script that imports from os and does severe damage. Some virtual sandbox where there is no way to get access to outside, just through few non-modifiable classes.

Comment: Why do the scripts have to be executed server side? Apart from security issues, what happens if one uses loads of processing power and memory?

Comment: have you checked docker?

Comment: @sweeneyrod no particular reason, it feels like the execution would be smoother, predictable, when run at the server side. Also, the scripts could be executed when the user is offline (ie, smart house control).

Comment: @RafaelBarros no, I have very little knowledge about its inner workings. It feels like it's used to scale and distribute ones apps, something where developers would put their project when it gets really huge.

Comment: @Passiday not exactly, that could be a tool to keep your insecure code in a sandbox, without affecting your environment, and it's far more lightweight than a VM. You could see a docker container, or any lxc actually, as a Virtual Machine without the absurd overhead.